# Rest API response to deserialise in to map to compare the data with other object.Value is not comparing and hence campaign data is not updating

Tags: api, rest

http request :

My intention here to compare the resopnse data with campaign  object data and then update the campaign

```
    Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
        String Query='SELECT campaign.advertising_channel_type,campaign.resource_name, metrics.all_conversions, metrics.cost_per_conversion,metrics.impressions,metrics.interaction_rate ,metrics.interactions,metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate,metrics.cost_per_all_conversions FROM campaign';
        httpReq.setEndpoint('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v3/customers/customerid/googleAds:search');
        httpReq.setMethod('POST');
        httpReq.setHeader('developer-token', 'developer token');
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer + Access token');
        httpReq.setHeader('login-customer-id', 'customerid');
        httpReq.setBody('query='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Query, 'UTF-8'));
        httpRes = (new Http()).send(httpReq);
            if(httpRes.getStatusCode() == 200){
                string response1= httpRes.getBody();
                System.debug('#### HtteRes '+HttpRes.getBody());
                Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response1);
             system.debug('response map values to verify'+ responseMap);

List<Campaign>campaignlist= New List<Campaign>([selectid,Campaign_ID__c,Clicks_Interactions__c,Impression__c,Conversion_rate__c,Conversions__c,Cost__c,Cost_per_conversion__c,CTR_Interaction_rate__c from Campaign where Campaign_ID__c!=null]);
                for(campaign Cg:campaignlist){
                 if(responseMap.containskey(cg.Campaign_ID__c) ){
cg.Impression__c= (integer)responseMap.get('metrics.impressions'); 
                }

}
}
```

HTTP repose:

```
"results": [
    {
      "campaign": {
        "resourceName": "customers/773406482280/campaigns/681356046220",
        "advertisingChannelType": "SEARCH"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "allConversions": 14,
        "costPerConversion": 503270000,
        "impressions": "122956",
        "interactionRate": 0.0097592713077423558,
        "interactions": "1250",
        "costPerAllConversions": 5032570000,
        "conversionsFromInteractionsRate": 0.0083333333333333332
      }
    },
    {
      "campaign": {
        "resourceName": "customers/773406482280/campaigns/7385351787266",
        "advertisingChannelType": "DISPLAY"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "allConversions": 0,
        "impressions": "5425072",
        "interactionRate": 0.00439240554369161294,
        "interactions": "2381",
        "conversionsFromInteractionsRate": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "campaign": {
        "resourceName": "customers/773406482280/campaigns/738556445107",
        "advertisingChannelType": "DISPLAY"
      },
      "metrics": {
        "allConversions": 0,
        "impressions": "4821",
        "interactionRate": 0.019085317776394939,
        "interactions": "92",
        "conversionsFromInteractionsRate": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "fieldMask": "campaign.advertisingChannelType,campaign.resourceName,metrics.allConversions,metrics.costPerConversion,metrics.impressions,metrics.interactionRate,metrics.interactions,metrics.conversionsFromInteractionsRate,metrics.costPerAllConversions"
}
```

Comment: Right now, I don't see a question being asked here. What is the problem you're having? Where are you stuck? You should [edit] your question to include that information (don't add it as a comment).

Answer (score 2):

This code won't work because you have a syntax error in your SOQL query:

```
List<Campaign>campaignlist= New List<Campaign>([selectid,Campaign_ID__c,Clicks_Interactions__c,Impression__c,Conversion_rate__c,Conversions__c,Cost__c,Cost_per_conversion__c,CTR_Interaction_rate__c from Campaign where Campaign_ID__c!=null]);
```

`selectid` should be `SELECT Id`.

But the real bug is here:

```
                for(campaign Cg:campaignlist){
                 if(responseMap.containskey(cg.Campaign_ID__c) ){
cg.Impression__c= (integer)responseMap.get('metrics.impressions'); 
                }
```

The `get()` method doesn't traverse dotted relationship paths. You must extract each level of structure individually from your JSON.

You'll have a much better time of it if you define a strongly-typed Apex class and deserialize that instead. The [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) tool can often help with this. You'll find scores, if not hundreds, of questions about JSON serialization on Salesforce Stack Exchange with a quick search.